# sample c# code to manage roles with roles provider

Tags: asp.net, roleprovider

i want to implement asp.net role provider to assign users over my LAN to roles and have my asp.net intranet app implement security based on roles.

i dont want to use VS to manage this with the built in tools but rather hand this off to users to manage themselves. i want an admin folder with a page(s) for admin roles to be able to create/edit roles and manage users in roles... this way an admin can add a domain user (MyDomain\Username) to a role such as ProojectManager or Tester or Developer... and users wont need to contact me for these tasks...

can anyone provide me a link (or some sample code) to some sample i can use to admin roles and users over a LAN in asp.net with c#?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4GuysFromRolla have a nice sample on creating your own website admin tool. :-)

https://web.archive.org/web/20210306174425/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx

And here's another....

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Web-Site-Administration-Tool.aspx